# Age not updating on profile

Tags: support, status-norepro, profile-page, dates

I turned 18 a few months ago, and haven't been on Stack Overflow for a while. But I was surprised to see when I took a look at my profile today, the age field hasn't updated despite the fact I actually inputted my date of birth rather than my actual age. It isn't updating when I hit edit and save it again, either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without revealing your actual birthdate, it still hasn't happened this year according to what I as a moderator can see in your profile -- it's not for quite a few more days yet in fact.

*unless you are posting this from the future!*

Comment: Sounds like Prior might be eager for their birthday.

Comment: Wait a minute...did he reverse the month and day fields, perhaps?

Comment: So yeah, I did actually end up reversing the month and day fields. That's what I get for being too used to DD/MM/YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a couple of hours.

The site is based on UTC and will count the years on your birthday cake based on that. So it might still be yesterday where you live based on timezones.