# Age not updating on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page, dates, age

I am having a similar issue reported in this question: [Age not updating on profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24298/189763).

I had a birthday several months ago, but my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299327/ryan-gates) still says the younger age.

This seems to be a bug, but please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: In other words, you're not aging. Now *that's* a breakthrough! :)

Comment: @Lucifer This question is not *Stack Overflow only*. Because his age is 26 in his all profiles.

Comment: Opps....hims....I just edited according to what OP said, I forgot to do that research.

Comment: I swear, SE doesn't handle dates well, they should hire Skeet for dealing with obscure dates!

Comment: @RichardJRoss are you refernceing [1927](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)? News flash: THAT'S ALREADY HAPPENED!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. The correct birth date format is `YYYY/MM/DD`, whereas I incorrectly entered it in the wrong format. The age now shows correctly.

It would be nice if there was something explaining the expected format though where you enter your birthday for your profile.

Comment: This is why we use standards, like ISO 8601.