# Display how birthday is interpreted on profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

This is primarily in response to the two below questions:

- [Age not updating on profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24298/189763)
- [Age not updating on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178415/189763)

The current birthday looks like the below:

[image]

It would be nice if following this, it could show how the birthday was interpreted. For example, the above would be the same but with a label showing:

[image]

I believe in both cases this would have prevented these unnecessary questions and improve the usability of the profile page.

P.S. I realize I didn't match the font/size exactly, but you get the idea.

Comment: Or just state that we use standard formats on SE, rather than small, local formats. =)

Comment: This is the [ISO date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and is unambigous primarily because there is no "local" format to confuse it with.

Comment: @Manishearth: Well, it's clearly been confusing to at least *one* person.

Comment: @Manishearth - Programmers might be expected to know about ISO date formats but what about [parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/) or [cooking](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)?. It isn't actually ISO format anyway because of the `/` AFAIK.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I didn't say that everyone had to know about it. I'm saying that it's reasonably easy to guess what it means since there's nothing to confuse it with -- all other formats have the year at the _end_. The descending order of YYY/MM/DD becomes logical then.