# Stack Exchange showing wrong age

Tags: support, stack-exchange

Stack exchange is showing my age 1 more year (19 year) than my actual age (18 years). I am not sure whether others are experiencing same issue or not. My birth date is (December, 1994)

Comment: Are you sure you put in the right birthday?

Comment: Yes December, 1994

Comment: Make sure you enter the date in an unambiguous way (`02/10/1994` is ambiguous - is that 10th of February or second of October?)

Comment: Note that when entering the _year_ first, the month comes second and day last.

Comment: Sorry, its my mistake. I wrote it in YYYY/DD/MM format. Should I delete this question?

Comment: ooo a typo question on meta :P

Comment: Laugh at me. I asked a silly question

Comment: So, as what do we close this? "Too Localized" is gone...and none of the other reasons fits.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby I also have no idea, that could be an interesting meta question.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: Perhaps it is *not* too localized? This was an on-topic support question, the answer is to enter your date in the correct format. That is *helpful information*.

Comment: I agree. Someone should post an answer then we can get on with our lives.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Age not updating on profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24298/age-not-updating-on-profile)

Comment: Not certain that is a helpful dupe target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expected format for the date of birth field in profiles is:

```
YYYY/MM/DD
```

This hint is only shown when the box is blank, however entering in this format should resolve your problem and your age should display correctly.