# So...as what do we close too localized questions now?

Tags: support

So we got [all new and shiny close reasons and a little bit reworked dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) which works very well and is very nice and handy. But there is one question left, as what do we close [too localized questions now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184416/stack-exchange-showing-wrong-age)?

It actually helps [to read the documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons), "too localized" was removed because it was misused most of the time:

> 5(A). "Too Localized" is no longer necessary since the specific
>   off-topic reasons now address its main use case. (new)
>
> Too Localized was, by far, the most misused close reason in our
>   surveys, with both Community Managers and Moderators deeming over 50%
>   of randomly sampled TL closures to not have merited closure (including
>   on SO).
>
> Today, TL is used helpfully on code dump questions on SO, but the new
>   OT reasons are where this is now correctly addressed. SO can use
>   "Large blocks of code with requests for debugging without meaningful
>   supporting info" as a specific OT reason.

But the new dialog leaves us with only four options:

> - Programming questions are off-topic on Meta Stack Overflow.
> - This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail.
> - Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.
> - Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)

Only the "other" reason does very well fit on "too localized" questions now, doe we close it with that?

Comment: You've listed the meta sub-reasons.  Is this question specific to meta?  Most "too localized" questions on meta would go with the third sub-reason.  If this isn't about meta; then the main site will have an entirely different set of sub reasons.

Comment: **[funniest example of  "Too Localized" I ever seen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)** - the question has about 200 upvotes, 27K views and about 80 linked questions. If that's TL then I don't know what isn't

Comment: @gnat "This question is **unlikely to help any future visitors**; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**". Accept rate is no longer around, so... yeah. ;)

Comment: @J.Steen that "specific moment in time" is several years of SE history. You know, in theory I can understand how this can be formally squeezed into TL, but 200 upvotes, 27K views and about 80 linked questions make this look very silly anyway

Comment: @gnat It **looks** silly, I agree, but the close reason is valid. What's more ironic is that the close reason could itself become too localised if we ever return accept rate. ^^

Comment: @J.Steen that made my day, thanks!

Comment: Can we/you pick a better example, or example_s_? This is a serious issue with the new close reasons that I want to air.

Answer (score 1):

From the [post you link to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons):

> **5(A). "Too Localized" is no longer necessary since the specific off-topic reasons now address its main use case. (new)**
>
> Too Localized was, by far, the most misused close reason in our surveys, with both Community Managers and Moderators deeming over 50% of randomly sampled TL closures to not have merited closure (including on SO).
>
> Today, TL is used helpfully on code dump questions on SO, but the new OT reasons are where this is now correctly addressed. SO can use "Large blocks of code with requests for debugging without meaningful supporting info" as a specific OT reason.

You close them as Off Topic, and you pick a reason that *fits the question*. There is no one OT reason that fits all valid Too Localized questions.

If you cannot fit it in a OT category, perhaps the question was not Too Localized in the first place?

For the [specific question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184416/stack-exchange-showing-wrong-age) that triggered this post in the first place, I do not think would warrant closing that one as Too Localized. It is a genuine support request, it is on topic, and can bite others. **You** may feel the issue is trivial, but it is not localized to one person or small geographical area. It should not be closed in the first place.

Comment: I just saw that, yes...but with what sub-reason?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby There won't be just one.  It will depend on the site that you're on, the specifics of the question, as well as what new sub-reasons end up being added (so far they're not finalized, and are of course subject to change over time).

Comment: Sub-reason: "Typo questions are off-topic on Meta. Ask it on the main site to get downvoted to oblivion."

Comment: @Servy: I'm not sure what you want to say, but my main point of view is that there is no option anymore to close *really* too localized questions (like mishaps during entering a date, see my example).

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby And my point is that there will be a new sub-reason for "offtopic" added to address that specific case.  It just doesn't exist on meta because that close reason doesn't apply to meta.  This isn't rolled out to SO yet.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: I am not certain that that question *is* too localized. That was the **point** of removing that closing reason.

Comment: "...perhaps the question was not Too Localized in the first place?" Oh, that's an idea...I have to think about that.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby As per the quote; 50% of TL questions weren't really TL, so a lot of questions previously closed shouldn't have been closed as TL to begin with.  Some just shouldn't have been closed, some should have been NARQ.

Comment: I agree that it's not too localized. It's been [asked](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24298/167443) at least [twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178415/167443). It's clearly something affecting multiple users (probably even more who just haven't noticed).