# May there be a put on hold reason for poster needs to debug their code?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, vote-to-close

There are many instances where a poster has an error which involves them debugging their own code. It turns into a comment disaster where everyone is posting fragments of code that are hard for the poster to read and when someone posts an answer of debug your code and specifically points out lines to debug, many people downvote the answer as not being an answer, but rather a comment. I feel these questions should be put on hold as "poster needs to debug".

Here is an example question [C#/SQL What seems to be wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071398/c-sql-what-seems-to-be-wrong/18071464#18071464)

Comment: Do you have an example of such a question?

Comment: See updated question for example.

Comment: @Emrakul This looks like a pretty good example of what the OP is talking about

Comment: @Chris See my answer below.

Comment: Related: [So... as what do we close too localized questions now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the "unclear what you're asking" reason is for. It's unclear what the OP is asking, because they simply haven't included enough information to accurately express their problem.

This is intended to avoid exactly this type of discussion, where nobody is really certain where the error is, because there's not enough information to tell. When you see these questions, close/flag as "unclear what you're asking."

Comment: I understand that is a viable choice, but I was thinking from a standpoint of if the question is put on hold, then if the reason given was more granular than the "unclear" choice, then it would stand a greater chance of potentially being reopened when the poster put more information about where there problem is actually occurring. Am I worrying about a problem that does not exist?

Comment: @Karl If a more specific close reason is picked, what gives it the additional chance?

Comment: re-open votes in the review process.

Comment: @Karl I can understand why you might have that impression, but I disagree with you. A user looking at an edited question will decide - regardless of the history of the question - whether the question is unclear. If the question is not unclear in its given state, regardless of the reason it was originally closed, then it will be reopened.

Comment: Fair enough, should I delete this question?

Comment: @Karl You actually can't at this point; it has an upvoted answer. Even so, I'd recommend you keep it here.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you help. I apologize for muddying the waters.