# What is the replacement for the old "too localized" OT reason? Other?

Tags: support, close-reasons, too-localized

I understand why the old "too localized" option was removed for OT posts closure reasons, but occasionally I still encounter posts that fall in this category.

For example, one recent questioner cited his professor's requirements and asked how he was supposed to write code to meet the requirements. Answering the question would have been valuable only to the students in that particular class, an obvious case of "too localized".

How are we supposed to flag such questions now? Use the "Other" category and just manually write in something like "This question will only help people in the student's class and is therefore too specific or localized for a general Q&A forum." In other words, writing out manually what used to be one of the choices?

Here is the actual question:

[ArrayList in C++, what is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22597161/arraylist-in-c-what-is-it)

Comment: It doesn't address that particular case, but one use of “too localized” was for questions caused by typos or unrelated configuration errors—something that now has its own off-topic close reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [So... as what do we close too localized questions now?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184436) and related to: [Now that too localized is gone, should we embrace the typo questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186181)

Comment: The case you quoted sounds "too broad" to me.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Both of the suggested "duplicates" do not answer my question. Also, one of the suggested duplicates was already itself marked as a duplicate, even though it did not answer the question either. The whole problem here is that the original post describing the changes does NOT say what to do when a question is too localized in the new system.

Comment: What do you consider "too localized?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey I gave an example in my question.

Comment: That one is Too Broad.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Too Broad" is when there are "too many possible answers". That is not the case in my example. His question had a single, specific answer, it's just that the answer would not be helpful to anyone because it would be specific to his class.

Comment: No, Too Broad fills two functions.  Too Broad is when there are too many possible answers (a "big list" question), or writing a good answer would fill a book, or the better part of a book chapter.

Comment: I disagree; I think Martijn's answer to "So...as what do we close..." explains what the intended replacement is. I don't _like_ the answer or agree that the replacement is satisfactory, but I think it's the answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, neither of those is the case here. The answer would be specific and relatively short.

Comment: Martijn's answer to [my proposed duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184436), @RobertHarvey.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: He says to close with a specific Off-Topic reason.  What is the specific, Off-Topic reason that should be used here?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Martijn's suggestion that "If you cannot fit it in a OT category, perhaps the question was not Too Localized in the first place?" is evasive and not an answer. It begs the question. I mean I realize that "Too Localized" was getting abused in the old system, but that does NOT mean there are no legitimate cases in which a question is too localized/too specific to the questioner.

Comment: I agree with you, @RobertHarvey, that the example Tyler provided sounds Too Broad, rather than "Off Topic".

Comment: Agreed, @TylerDurden; I was not happy that Too Localized was removed, nor that [so-called "Off Topic"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192146/159251) was the replacement.

Comment: As a close reason "Too Localized" doesn't exist anymore.  Not too put too fine a point on this, but really what that means is that there is no such thing as "Too Localized."  Find another close reason that fits, or downvote the question and move on.

Comment: That question is off-topic because it's about asking your professor to clarify your homework assignment, not programming. :)

Comment: "What is an ArrayList in C++" is *not* Too Localized.  It is a great number of other things that the community finds irritating, but it is decidedly not too localized.  Before you figure out what to replace Too Localized with, you have to first understand what Too Localized is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey On reading the "typo" meta question more thoroughly, it appears you already answered my question in a comment, "...I am just deleting those posts. There really isn't a close reason that fits anymore, and I'm loathe to request a replacement for "Too Localized..."--RobertHarvey. So, your answer would seem to be, don't vote to close anymore, flag for moderator under "Other" and request deletion.

Comment: Since that time, a close reason has been added that fits the scenario I was describing in that comment.  It is the "typo" close reason.  The question you cited is *still* not Too Localized, nor does it suffer from a simple typo problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I agree that on a certain level, the example question here is not even a programming question at all, its a "What the heck did my professor mean" question, so in that case maybe OT Not a Programming Question is right. So, maybe my example was poorly chosen.